# ¿Como recuperar el valor del item seleccionado en un Dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola tengo un Dropdownlist el cual se llena con los nombre de una tabla de base de datos, asi es como lo lleno:

```html
 <asp:DropDownList ID="Dropdownlist1" runat="server" class="form-control mr-sm-2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged"
DataTextField="Nombre" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
```

```html
  public void llenaDDL()
  {
  con.Open();           
string query = "select Id, Nombre from Personas where IdRegion='" + Session["IdRegion"]+"' order by Nombre asc";
  SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
  cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds, "Personas");
  Dropdownlist1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Personas"];
  Dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "Id";
  Dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "Nombre";
  Dropdownlist1.DataBind();
  con.Close();
 }
```

Ahora lo que necesito es que cuando el usuario cambie el nombre en el Dropdownlist se actualice un gridview con los datos del nombre seleccionado, lei que el metodo para esto era Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged, este el mi codigo pero no hace nada

```html
protected void Dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
string id = Dropdownlist1.SelectedValue;
if (id == null)
{
    loadGrid();
}
else
{
con.Open();
string query1 = "select * from notas where id='"+id+"'";
SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
cm1.CommandTimeout = 0;
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cm1);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da1.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sino se ejecuta el evento del `dropdownlist` se debe a que te esta faltando asignar la propiedad

`AutoPostBack` en `true`

sin definir esta propiedad el evento al servidor no se realiza

[AutoPostBack Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListControl_AutoPostBack)